# Is there any way to get a variable address in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, memory-address, xor-linkedlist

I'm trying to implement XOR-linked lists on Common Lisp, but i need to get an address of a variable to perform any bitwise operations on it.
Is there any way to get memory address of a variable, similar to python's id() function?

Comment: If you need low-level things like addresses, Common Lisp is not the right tool; but it is a very good tool for high-level programming. Why do you need XOR-linked lists in Lisp?

Comment: In Common Lisp addresses of variables make very little sense. Variables are often just pointers to objects.

Comment: Garbage collection can move things around,and some entire can be copied whenever the implementation wants.  So there's no reliable sense of address for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might find an [unrolled linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list) easier to implement in Common Lisp, with many of the same memory advantages.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch actually, i was trying to do it just for the sake of doing it. I was interested if this can be implemented in lisp, and how hard it is to implement.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I believe it is more appropriate to say that *values* are pointers to "objects" and variables contain such values

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I was trying to implement double-linked list, and as i saw it, xor-linked lists are a best way to implement using cons-cells. I guess i was wrong

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: compare the definition of 'value' in Common Lisp: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_v.htm#value and also see  variable under http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_v.htm#variable

Answer (score 7):

Usually, memory management in Common Lisp is performed by some kind of [Garbage Collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). Many of these algorithms move the objects in memory during a collection cycle.

So the consequencies are that you cannot count on a fixed address for each object, and for this reason no operation in the standard is provided to get the address of a Common Lisp object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Allegro Common Lisp](http://franz.com/products/allegro-common-lisp/), maybe this is what you're looking for:
[Escape from the Heap: Low-Level Programming in Common Lisp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7nEZ3TuFpA)